Getting internal server error in my perl cgi script on the line: use CGI qw(:standard);
I am trying to run an apache web server, which would take my html form, process it, and would give some kind of answer. I had problems installing cgi, configuring it, but I managed to do it. Now I am getting an error "internal server error" when I am trying to check the perl script using curl. When I check the apache error logs, it says that it aborted because of the 3 line, which is: use CGI qw(:standard);
Here is my simple code:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

# Enable taint mode
use diagnostics;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
# print header(-type => 'text/html', -charset => 'utf-8'). 
#     start_html('Form Submission Results');

my $sequence = param('sequence');
my $alignment_type = param('alignment-type');
my $organism = param('organism');
my $sequence_length = param('sequence-length');
my $confidence_level = param('confidence-level');

# Check for missing data
if (!$sequence || !$alignment_type || !$organism || !$sequence_length || !$confidence_level) {
    print h1("Error: Missing Data");
    print p("Please fill all the fields.");
    print end_html;
    exit;
}

# Basic validation (simulating complex processing)
if ($sequence !~ /^[ACGT]+$/i) {
    print h1("Error: Invalid Sequence");
    print p("Sequence must contain only A, C, G, or T for DNA.");
    print end_html;
    exit;
}

# Simulate processing
print h1('Sequence Alignment Results');
print p("Alignment Type: $alignment_type");
print p("Organism: $organism");
print p("Sequence Length: $sequence_length");
print p("Confidence Level: $confidence_level");

print end_html;

I have tried removing cgi use lines, then I get no error, but then server doesn't return anything.

What error are you actually getting? "Aborted because of the 3 line" is not a message that Perl produces.

"BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/form.pl line 4." This is the error I am getting.

CGI is not recommended any longer. It has a section of it's documentation with details. https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE

use diagnostics does not enable taint. It enables verbose warnings. Taint is enabled with the -T switch.

If you had problems installing CGI, then you probably did something wrong and that's why it is not working. Instead of trying to fix it, though, check CGI::Alternatives for a better module to use, since CGI is outdated and no longer recommended.

Also note from the CGI.pm documentation: All HTML generation functions within CGI.pm are no longer being maintained. Any issues, bugs, or patches will be rejected unless they relate to fundamentally broken page rendering.

"BEGIN failed--compilation aborted" simply means another error happened earlier. So again, what error you are actually getting?

Solved it using:
sudo apt-get install libcgi-pm-perl

Needed to install the library because apparently new Perl versions doesn't come with it anymore.
But it is very strange, that there was nothing on the error logs.

new perl versions doesn't have it from the start as they did before CGI.pm was removed from core almost a decade ago... at this point, old perl versions don't have it, much less new ones.

Re "it is very strange, that there were nothing on the error logs.", What do you mean? You literally quoted the error logs in an earlier comment.

@ikegami I was expecting an error like: There is no such library or perl cannot find this library. Not just the "error on th eline 4".

@mmartiss If a library is missing, the error would be Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Sjdjs module) (@INC contains: ....

Also, you said in the main question that you had already installed CGI. So that makes this answer strange.

Perl does not produce messages of the form error on th eline 4. As TLP said, the error you are asking about has the form Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CGI module) (@INC entries checked: <@INC>) at <$script line> <$line_num>., which is basically exactly what you said you wanted (but better).

@TLP Re "you said in the main question that you had already installed CGI.", Since they said they had problems installing and configuring CGI, I suspect they were referring to CGI support in apache rather than CGI.pm

@ikegami That would make sense.
